# How to write this in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This following code is taken from FastImageCache git repository. How I can write this in Swift?

```
FICEntityImageDrawingBlock drawingBlock = ^(CGContextRef context, CGSize contextSize) 
{
     CGRect contextBounds = CGRectZero;
     contextBounds.size = contextSize;
     CGContextClearRect(context, contextBounds);

     ....

     UIGraphicsPopContext();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let drawingBlock: FICEntityImageDrawingBlock = { context, contextSize in
    let contextBounds = CGRectZero
    contextBounds.size = contextSize
    CGContextClearRect(context, contextBounds)

    ...

    UIGraphicsPopContext()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Previously I was trying this which was throwing me error:

"let drawingBlock: FICEntityImageDrawingBlock = {
                (contextRef: CGContextRef, contextSize: CGSize) in". Error: Cannot convert value of type '(CGContextRef, CGSize) -> ()' to specified type 'FICEntityImageDrawingBlock' (aka '(ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<CGContext>, CGSize) -> ()'). Later when I tried (as you suggested) it worked well!
"let drawingBlock: FICEntityImageDrawingBlock = {
                (contextRef, contextSize) in". 
So it looks like I was adding extra name ref to the arguments!

Answer (score 1):

This is how it'd look, the main change is the first line, where you use `(parameters) in`.

```
let drawingBlock: FICEntityImageDrawingBlock = { (context: CGContextRef, size: CGSize) in
    let bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    CGContextClearRect(context, bounds);
    //...
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Comment: I tried with this previously already - but it was throwing me error: Cannot convert value of type '(CGContextRef, CGSize) -> ()' to specified type 'FICEntityImageDrawingBlock' (aka '(ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<CGContext>, CGSize) -> ()'). Later I removed name refs and it worked - "let drawingBlock: FICEntityImageDrawingBlock = { context, contextSize in"

Answer (score 1):

I have converted the objective C block code into Swift code for you...

```
// Object-C FICEntityImageDrawingBlock definition 
// void (^FICEntityImageDrawingBlock)(CGContextRef context, CGSize contextSize);
// Swift code
let drawingBlock : FICEntityImageDrawingBlock = {( context, contextSize) in
            var contextBounds : CGRect = CGRectZero;
            contextBounds.size = contextSize;
            CGContextClearRect(context, contextBounds);
            UIGraphicsPopContext();
        }
```

You can also converted any objective-C block code into swift code very easy. Have a look on the one more example -

```
 // Objecttive C Block
   void (^completionBlock)(NSData *, NSError *) = ^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            // ...
        }

 // Swift Block
    let completionBlock: (NSData, NSError) -> Void = { (data, error) in
            // ...
        }
```

For more details you can refer [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html)